# SQL LIMIT doesn't work with define

Tags: php, sql, limit, sql-limit

I am writing an SQL request in PHP. the request worked fine like this:

```
$testQuery = "SELECT `title` FROM `bibliography` Where title LIKE '%$search%'";
```

I need to add a limit. If I add a LIMIT with a number it works fine:

```
$testQuery = "SELECT `title` FROM `bibliography` Where title LIKE '%$search%' LIMIT 5";
```

but if i use a define:

```
define( 'PAGING', 2 );
$testQuery = "SELECT `title` FROM `bibliography` Where title LIKE '%$search%' LIMIT PAGING";
```

it throws an error:

> Undeclared variable: PAGING SQL=SELECT `title` FROM `bibliography`
>   Where title LIKE '%%' LIMIT PAGING

However in other parts of the code PAGING works fine. Why this doesn't work and how can I use a define for a limit?

Comment: Tag dbms used. (E.g. LIMIT is product specific.)

Comment: you have defined a constant but is treated in the sql as a string. You need to break out from the quoted string first. `$testQuery = "SELECT title FROM bibliography Where title LIKE '%$search%' LIMIT ".PAGING.";";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you pass a variable in query like this instead of constant? (or it must be constant)

```
$define = 5;
$testQuery = "SELECT `title` FROM `bibliography` Where title LIKE '%$search%' LIMIT $define";
```